# Windows phone 7: facing issue for passing parameters

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-7

Right now i am developing a Windows phone app, yes this is my first windows app. Right now i am facing an issue, don't know what's the silly mistake i made. Yes of course i have done debugging.

Now, what exactly i am doing?

1. Passing data from 1st page to 2nd page,
2. On the page, catching data inside onNavigateTo() method, yes i am receiving it correctly.
3. Based on the parameter/data (i.e. ID) i got, i am making web service call.

**Problem:
If i move to the 3rd page from 2page and again came back to the 2nd page, its again making web call.** i.e. calling `DownloadStringAsync` again in below code.

i.e. If 2nd page is having ListBox with 5 data, now clicking on particular item i am moving to 3rd page, if i came back to 2nd page from page 3, items get doubled i.e. 10 items (just because its making call again)

Here is the possible code for the reference:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
       base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

       type = Convert.ToInt32(NavigationContext.QueryString["Type"]);
       if (type != 0)
       {
           if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
           {
              client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(Utils.Constant.WebService_URL));
            }
            else
            {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please check internet connection!!");
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't you use the following code to test if the user used the back button?

```
e.NavigationMode == System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationMode.Back
```

Answer (score 0):

sometimes this method(QueryString)  create problems.

In back event it create problems
its betters to store the id(parameter) in isolatedstorage application key

IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["id"] = "your data";

Answer (score 0):

`OnNavigatedTo` is called whenever you navigate to the page, either by a forward navigation, or a back navigation. That's why it's retriggered when you navigate back from page #3 to page #2.

You can avoid this by only triggering the network call on a forward navigation.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
   base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

   if (this.isInitialized) return;

   type = Convert.ToInt32(NavigationContext.QueryString["Type"]);
   if (type != 0)
   {
       if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
       {
          client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(Utils.Constant.WebService_URL));
        }
        else
        {
                MessageBox.Show("Please check internet connection!!");
        }
    }
    this.isInitialized = true;
}
```

Beware that `NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable` can block (in this case the UI thread) for a long time in some scenarios, to work around this you can use [network detection events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh487166%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the answer with a valuable suggestion. Now, if i include isInitialized line then its displaying error, when i put mouse pointer there, its showing 2 options: **initialized property stub for isInitialized and **initialized field stub for isInitialized**? Which one is the correct one?

Comment: You need to create the boolean `this.isInitialized` field (not shown in my answer).